# What difference between extends and = in generic types?

Tags: typescript

What difference between these two functions? Both work the same. I know how extends work in interfaces but I can't understand the differences here

```js
const func = <T extends string>(str: T): T => str
```

```js
const func = <T = string>(str: T): T => str
```

Comment: "*Both work the same.*" no, they don't at all. `extends X` places a restriction on the generic - it has to be assignable to `X`. While `= X` just means that the default generic value, if not explicitly passed in or inferred, would be `X`. It doesn't restrict anything. You can call the second one as `func<number>(42)` but not the first one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript generic type with equal operator means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843790/typescript-generic-type-with-equal-operator-means) and [Typescript generic type parameters: T vs T extends {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61648189)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are very different things.

---

```
<T extends string>
```

This is a *constraint*. This means that `T` must be `string` or a subtype of `string` (i.e. a string literal)

```
const func = <T extends string>(str: T): T => str

func("A") // returns type "A" because "A" is a subtype of string
func<string>("A") // returns type string because the inference was overridden
func(123) // error 123 is not a subtype of string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeAKjApgDylzABMIZoAnASzAHMA+ACioC4YsBKdnVBiqJQBQQxMiYAiAIITOMAPTyYlXFASVIMKAE8ADrhjSJMAEa5gAQwQQDRmNXIWKCEzv0wQcATXqikwDCpaRkkZOUVlVXVNNwMg+lNzKxstAAsDWjhcFWQDAHcLchAAN2yaEhJiP3EARgAmAGZwpTKQShh6hvtyMBBYJwgXWI8veLogA)

---

```
<T = string>
```

This is a *default* type. In this case `T` is not constrained, but if omitted `string` is used as the type of `T`.

```
const func = <T = string>(str: T): T => str

func("A") // returns type "A" because "A" is a inferred for T
func<string>("A") // returns type string because the inference was overridden
func(123) // returns type 123 because 123 is inferred as the type for T
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeAKmm0BOAlmAOYB8AFAQFwxYCUtOqZeU+AUB4shQEQBBPvRgB6UTHwBTKAnyQYUAJ4AHKTEF8YAIynAAhggjrNMQhBj6zYOFPzSAJvBD463JMAwFi5fkJHikjJyCspqbESkOnqGxooAFurEttLI6gDu+hYgAG52RA4OUmDuvACMAEwAzAES0rLyFmHqlVXRBkYt1WYWyflSTlkJ6s3OrlhAA)

The default type doesn't make a lot of sense in this example though since it is inferred by the argument when you omit it. So lets look at a different example:

```
type MyType<T = string> = { value: T }
type TestA = MyType<number> // equivalent to { value: number }
type TestB = MyType // equivalent to { value: string }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq4IB55QLxQM7AE4EsA7AcwD4MoBvKANwEMAbAVwgC4o0BfAKFEg4g4AghTiJIyQkwC2AIwi5yAeiVQIARyb56DCIWBRgAeyq1GLdlLkKoPPtHiDgAIVEIkUFWs3bGeg8amOhbYeETEtkA)

Note how in `TestB` you can leave out the generic, and the default of `string` is used instead.

However, in the case of `T extends string` both `TestA` and `TestB` are type errors:

```
type MyType<T extends string> = { value: T }
type TestA = MyType<number> // type error: number does not extend string
type TestB = MyType // type error: missing generic parameter
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=60&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq4IB55QgD2BAdgEwGcoDgAnASxwHMA+KAXigG8oA3AQwBsBXCALihoAvgChQkQRBIBBBrARJkObgFsARhFJ0A9Nqjjom0gHtSA5es1Q8xqVBzHg6LLjzEylKmKSSSAITk4RAldfR8jUwEVcgICTygqXE1yAGMoMHZSdhVsUiA)

Comment: I have doubt in this line  const func = <T = string>(str: T): T => str and I dint found answer to it when I searched. My doubt is, why we need to put  :T  after (str:T) ? remaining part of the line I have understood.