# Why Promise.reject().catch(() => 5) valid for Typescript

Tags: typescript

Could you help me understand why TS compiler doesn't complain about this statement?

```
Promise.reject().catch(() => 5)
```

If checking the [definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#LL1531C51-L1531C54) of the handler function inside the `catch` we can see the piece of code as follows:

```
interface Promise<T> {
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;

    catch<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): Promise<T | TResult>;
}
```

It assumes that the handler function returns `TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>` where `TResult = never`. And then in my example a handler function returns `5` which is a `number`. So I could assume that `5` is `never | PromiseLike<never>`. But it is not the case. A `number` doesn't have `.then` function so it's not a `PromiseLike`.
Thanks!

Comment: ... Well no, `TResult` is **inferred** `number`, so it's actually `number | PromiseLike<number>`, and `5` is assignable to that type. If you have an editor with language support, you should hover over the `catch` call to see what the types are.

Comment: `TResult` just *defaults* to `never` according to that signature. It’s not *constrained* to it.  It’s the difference between `=` and `extends`.

Comment: Relevant: [typescript generic type with equal operator means?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56843790)

Comment: @zenly Thanks! Didn't know if hovering in IDE it will show the type by inferring

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for sharing the difference between `extends` and `=`. I wasn't aware of it

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the reference! Very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't complain because the type parameter `TResult` in that definition of `catch()` method just [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `never`. The type parameter `TResult` is not [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `never` in any way.

Note that the `=` operator inside a type parameter declaration is a *default type argument*, while the `extends` operator inside a type parameter declaration is a *type parameter constraint*.  In general you can have neither or either or both.  A type parameter declaration on a call signature like `<T extends C = D>(⋯) => ⋯` means that `T` must be assignable to `C`, and if `T` cannot be inferred, it will default to `D` (which must also be assignable to the constraint `C`).  If you leave out `C` then it is equivalent to specifying it as [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown), and if you leave out `D` then it is equivalent to specifying it as `C`.  So `<TResult = never>` is equivalent to `<TResult extends unknown = never>`, meaning it defaults to `never` but is not constrained at all.

So: `TResult` will only fall back to `never` in the event that it cannot be inferred from the input, such as if the `onrejected` argument is not supplied.  But you *did* supply an `onrejected` argument of `() => 5`. And thus TypeScript was able to infer the `TResult` type argument as `number`,  because `() => 5` is a valid `((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null`.  You can verify this by hovering over the `catch` call in an IntelliSense-enabled IDE:

```
Promise.reject().catch(() => 5)
// (method) Promise<never>.catch<number>(
//    onrejected?: ((reason: any) => number | PromiseLike<number>) | null | undefined
// ): Promise<number>
```

So everything's working as expected and intended here.

Answer (score 0):

Since the callback function returns a value of 5, the new promise created by catch() is resolved with that value. Meaning, the new promise created by catch() is resolved with the value of 5 because the callback function returns that value.

Comment: How does this address the question, which is "why doesn't the TS compiler complain about this when `number` is not assignable to `PromiseLike<never>`?"

Comment: TypeScript should still complain because the catch() method is expecting a PromiseLike object as its return value. But the callback function returns the value 5, which is a valid value for a promise to resolve to, meaning the new promise created by catch() is resolved with that value. In TypeScript, a promise can be of any type, so a promise that resolves to the value 5 is perfectly valid.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "TypeScript should still complain".  It doesn't complain.  So do you really mean that it *should*?  If so, why doesn't it?  If not, why say that?

Comment: I meant  number is not assignable to PromiseLike<never>, so still  we would expect that TS would complain, but it didn't, why it didn't? because the call back returns a integer value, which doesn't matter which type is it, still is perfectly resolvable :) I need some one to edit me.

Comment: Either I'm not understanding what you're saying, or what you are saying is incorrect or not relevant.  TypeScript doesn't have higher-order reasoning abilities that would enable it to ignore a detected type error because it's "resolvable".  Any answer to this question should address the misconception that `<TResult = never>` implies that `TResult` will be `never`.  Since your answer makes no mention of this whatsoever, and neither do your comment replies, I'm worried that you're just saying "it's not an error because it's fine", which doesn't really engage with the question as asked.

Comment: Let's focus on the reason "why the TypeScript compiler does not complain about the Promise.reject().catch(() => 5)" statement. I think it's because the catch() method in the Promise<T> interface is defined to accept a function that returns T | PromiseLike<T>. Since the original returns never, then the catch is called and gets 5 as return. But  TS inferes it that the return is a number and not of a promislike<never.